# External application writing to access DB

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I really tried to find examples, syntax etc. but it always redirects me to excel questions. Maybe I use a completely wrong approach.

So I am writing currently a windows application with visual studio 2015 in vba code.
Mainly this program will collect information that are typed into textboxes and then will be saved in a small database.
Originally I used Excel as my "testdatabase", but the main problem there is that it can only be accessed by one user and it is obviously not suitable for a db. Now I want to change my code to use a MS Access DB, but I just cannot wrap my head around how to do it.
I am absolutely not familiar with DB coding :(

The code for my old program using excel:

```
    ' Start Excel and get Application object. 
    oXL = New Excel.Application

    ' Set some properties 
    oXL.Visible = False
    oXL.DisplayAlerts = False     

    Dim wkbk As Excel.Workbook = oXL.Workbooks.Add

    'add(worksheet)

    wkbk.Worksheets.Add()

    'open existing work        

    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\database\Productionplan.xlsx", ReadOnly:=False)

    ' Get the active sheet 
    oSheet = DirectCast(oWB.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)
    oSheet.Name = "Sheet1"

    oSheet.Cells(index, 3).value = po.Text
    oSheet.Cells(index, 4).Value = product.Text
    oSheet.Cells(index, 5).Value = drawings.Text
    oSheet.Cells(index, 6).Value = customer.Text
    oSheet.Cells(index, 7).Value = assemblingdate.Text
    oSheet.Cells(index, 8).Value = deliverydate.Text
    oSheet.Cells(index, 9).Value = voltage.Text
    oSheet.Cells(index, 10).Value = power.Text
    oSheet.Cells(index, 11).Value = serialno.Text
    oSheet.Cells(index, 12).Value = quantity.Text
    oSheet.Cells(index, 13).Value = unit.Text


    ' Save the sheet and close 
    oSheet = Nothing
    oRange = Nothing
    oWB.SaveAs("C:\database\Productionplan.xlsx")
    oWB.Close()
    oWB = Nothing
    oXL.Quit()
```

Is there a similar easy way to write values into specific cell in an access database? 
Thank you for your help. Would be already helpful if someone knows a tutorial site or something. As soon as I have some simple sample code to access a cell in a db, I should be able to figure how to transfer my code to access db.

Best Regards
Dom

Edit: add some pictures
[datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgXZd.png)

[application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlrlL.png)

Comment: Databases don't have "cells".  They have tables, which have records, which have fields.  Search for ADODB and DAO.

Comment: I did use OLEDB to connect and read my table, I am also able to add new records to the table. But I don't know how I can edit specific records by using my programs variables to count etc. I assume I have to use some query to do that?

Comment: You can use non-scalar sql statements for inserts (INSERT INTO) and edits (UPDATE [table] SET ...) Counts you can do with scalar sql statements  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...).

Comment: Your question asks to insert records but now you say you've managed that and you want to edit. Are you still building this in Excel VBA? Since we don't know what your database looks like and how exactly you want to edit, no one can answer your question at this stage. Perhaps you could pursue using a grid control.

Comment: Sorry if its not clear. Not sure if it is what you mean: I do not use the excel vba editor. I use visual studio 2015 to program a windows application. I just used excel as sort of database, which i now want to replace with an access database. My Database looks very simple: just has a top row. About 11 columns and all data below will be populated by the user using textboxes for input. I managed to insert records by usind INSERT Into. I just wanted to ask if there is a similar way as above, because I find it easier to address the specific cell. now I learned this is not possible.

Comment: added some pictures

Comment: Databases have tightly bound records. There's no arbitrary cell. You first identify the row. You identify it by one or more column values. Then yuo use an update statement for example. This is why MS Access (and every database) recommends you have a primary key (i.e. Autonumber). You can use the key to identify the row then use an update statement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this where field1,... will be the table column names, and "value1",... from the textboxes

```
Dim objRS As Object ' optional
Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objRS.Open "INSERT INTO [table 1] ( [field 1] , [field 2] ) " & _ 
                         " VALUES (""value 1"",""value 2"");", _ 
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\test.mdb"

Set objRS = Nothing ' optional
```